# Twitter searching for two lists

Tags: twitter, embed, twitter-search

I'd like to embed two lists in same timeline on my website. I'm trying to search for two Twitter lists using Twitter search but i can't make it work.

I'm able to do it i.e. with two accounts.    `from:NASA OR from:NBA`

But it doesn't work with lists    `list:NASA/astronauts-in-space-now OR list:NBA/ESPN`

Am I doing something wrong here or is this even possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

The `list:[handle]/[list-name]` is a `filter` operator and not a Boolean argument, therefore impossible to use twice (two list filters) in the same search.

Depending on what you wish to do with the results of such (necessary) two separate searches, you can merge their respective results into one unified place like another Tweeter feed or a designated Google Sheet using a free web automation service like [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/).

You'll need to create two separate IFTTT recipes. The first will have as trigger a Twitter search for the `list:NASA/astronauts-in-space-now`, the second will have as trigger a Twitter search for the `list:NBA/ESPN`.

For both recipes, use **the same** Google Sheet (new line) or Twitter Account (new tweet) as an action, and throw the content triggered by both recipes into a unified table / account.